# Scheme Lambda Return Values

Tags: lambda, scheme, read-eval-print-loop

Scheme is about to drive me crazy. In the code below I am simply trying to parse the string given to repl into an actual list. Instead when I print what is supposed to be my parsed list all I get is a list of right parends! I am using the following site to test my code:
http://repl.it/

I am fully expecting my code to create a list like the following:
(+ 1 2)
or perhaps this since I'm not how types work in scheme.
("+" "1" "2")

Any help as to why my list looks like the following is much appreciated:
() ) ))

```
(define repl
      (lambda (input)
          (define symbol_list (Read input))
          ;(define value (eval symbol_list))
          ;(myprint value)
          ;(print (length symbol_list))
          (print symbol_list)
      )
)

(define Read
      (lambda (input)
          (define symbol (substring input 0 1))
          (cond
              ((string=? ")" symbol) '())
              ((or (string=? "(" symbol) (string=? " " symbol))
                  (Read (substring input 1 (string-length input))))
              (else (cons symbol (Read (substring input 1 (string-length input)))))
          )
  )
)

(repl "(+ 1 2)")
```

Comment: That's weird, the code as posted here is returning `'("+" "1" "2")`, which I guess is the correct value you're expecting

Comment: Really? Did you use the same interpreter I linked too?

Comment: No, I used Racket. Looks like the problem is with the interpreter, not your code

Comment: Ah ok. I'm installing Racket now to test it out myself. I sure had a headache trying to figure out what was wrong, hopefully this is it.

Comment: Also, see my answer below, there's a simpler way to do what you want

Comment: Yep it worked fine in Racket. Thanks a lot for testing it in a different interpreter, I guess I'll stick to racket from now on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is working, I tested it in Racket - there might be a problem with the interpreter you're using to test it.

By the way, what you want to do can be accomplished using built-in procedures, like this:

```
(read (open-input-string "(+ 1 2)"))
=> '(+ 1 2) ; a list of symbols/numbers, not strings
```

Comment: Wow thanks, that is a lot handier. My only question is, how can I compare the + operator? Before, since + was a string I could use string=? but is there a special comparison operator for comparing literal operators such as +, -, *, etc.?

Comment: Use `symbol=?`. For example: `(symbol=? (car '(+ 1 2)) '+) => #t`. And use `=` for numbers. Or simply use `equal?` which works for all types